# Изменение ориентации дисплея Android

Tags: android, экран, orientation

Нужно перевернуть ориентацию дисплея на 180 градусов, и зафиксировать.
Добавление в `build.prop` строки `ro.sf.hworientation=180` не помогло.

Answer (score 1):

Можно в описание активности в манифесте добавить `android:screenOrientation=reversePortrait` или `android:screenOrientation=reserveLandscape`

Comment: Вопрос, скорее не о написании приложения, а о всей системе в целом. Я хочу заставить android считать что дефолтный landscape режим, это текущий landscape + 180 градусов (вверх ногами). Моя цель - это перевернуть дисплей, и пользоваться андроидом без неудобств.